# How to submit the form to a different server and from that server return to the same page php

Tags: php

I'm trying to verify user apiKey. so the I have a application which user installs on their server and they need to add their apiKey to activate it. so I've created a form where they can add their apiKey and it'll submit the key to my server and then my server verify the key. **but I want to know how to get from which URL we recieved the request so we can send back results to that url?**

```
<form action="my-server-.com/verifyfile.php" method="post">                                 
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Enter API Key</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="text" placeholder="paste your api key here" name="apiKey" class="form-control" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Register" name="verify-api" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">                
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You first want to store the url then you will respond to the url later?

Comment: but why would you want to respond to a url.  why wouldn't you just echo out the result in your page so that the referrer would pick the response for themselves i.e. in json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i have understood your question,

> 1. someone sends an apiKey to your site
> 2. you capture the apiKey
> 3. you verify the apiKey
> 4. after verifying the apiKey you respond to the url that submitted the apiKey

Below php code can sit in your server on a php page to do the task

```
<?php
//If the API Key is sent lets validate it
if (isset($_GET['apiKey'])) {

   $apikey = $_GET['apiKey'];  //The apikey

   if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {   
   $from_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
   } else 
   { 
   die(); //end 
   }


   //Do your validation for the apiKey
   if ($apikey == 'is_okay') { //do your own validation to test if its okay

    //what you want to append to the url received
    $query_parameter = 'result=yes'; 

   //append your parameter strings to the url you want to respond to
   if(strpos($from_url,'?') !== false) {
    $from_url .=  '&'.$query_parameter;
   } else {
    $from_url .=  '?'.$query_parameter;
   }

   //your site then automatically navigates to the url with an appended query string
   header('Location: '.$from_url);

   } else { 
   die(); //do something here if apiKey not verified 
   }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you can make redirect back to url from where they came,but for some interaction you cant without proper code on client/user server side
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
'HTTP_REFERER'
The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.
```

Comment: I'm planning to use get method to submit to my server. but I want to know how am I gonna return result to the same page from my server.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. how my script will know from which URL we received the request? is there any function or something for that?

Comment: you looking for $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] i updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use Curl.

```
  <?php
    if (isset($_POST['apiKey'])) {
                $api_key = $_POST['apiKey'];
            } else {
                $api_key = '';
            }

    //You can use Curl...
    $ch = curl_init();

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 
      "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://urltoAnotherserver.com"); 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $api_key);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

                $json = curl_exec($ch);
                $response = json_decode($json, TRUE);

                print_r($response);

                curl_close($ch);
```

And when you receive response you can verify the key in php