# how to hit the API by using CURL?

Tags: php, json, api, codeigniter, curl

i try to hit the API by using curl
in this case i try to hit : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

```
  <?php

class process extends CI_Controller {


    $headers = 'Content-Type:application/json';



    $process = curl_init('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'); //your API url
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $return = curl_exec($process);
    curl_close($process);

    //finally print your API response
    print_r($return);

}
```

but it shows some errors like this

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: ParseError
>
> Message: syntax error, unexpected '$headers' (T_VARIABLE), expecting
>   function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)
>
> Filename: E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Crudview\application\controllers\process.php
>
> Line Number: 6
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Crudview\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Comment: You have a class created, but not a function. Please look into how [classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) are built.

Comment: maybe you find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247201/how-to-submit-the-form-to-a-different-server-and-from-that-server-return-to-the/60247321#60247321

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use like that:-

```
<?php

class process extends CI_Controller {

    function curlAPI(){
        $headers = 'Content-Type:application/json';
        $process = curl_init('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'); //your API url
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $return = curl_exec($process);
        curl_close($process);
        print_r($return);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Please be aware that controllers shouldn't have the php tag closed. I would make a edit suggestion but stackoverflow requires me to edit at least 6 characters.